# reaching the NAS Fileserver with OpenVPN

Tags: linux, windows, routing, openvpn

i installed VPN on Server and Client.

Both nets are connected via VPN Tunnel from 10.8.0.x (Client x for destinated ip of the client) to 10.8.0.1 (Server VPN IP). Open VPN works and even Microsoft Remotedesktop does connect to the ips 10.8.0.1 and 192.168.2.113. But ping does not work. Ping on Fileserver (192.168.2.21) does also not work

From Server (192.168.2.113) ping to Fileserver (192.168.2.21) works.

But i cant reach the Fileserver from the Client. Even the Internet Connection works cause all is forwareded back to the router of the destination net. What have i done wrong? Or what is missing that i can reach my Fileserver? Thank you a lot for answers.

2 Nets

Net 1

Router: 192.168.2.1 Firewall off for testing OpenVPN Port forwarded to VPN Server

VPN Server: 192.168.2.113 Remotedesktop enabled and SQL Server running OpenVPN Server configured and running

NAS-Linux Fileserver: 192.168.2.21

Net 2

My PC: 192.168.4.100 My Router: 192.168.4.1

Routing
[VPN Server Routing Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfJWH.jpg)
[My Client PCs Routing Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqUyg.jpg)

Comment: sadly no one gives an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you have described, it's very likely that your NAS is "locking" the subnet.

My guess is that your NAS is locked to 192.168.2.1/24 or 192.168.4.1/24 and not including the 10.8.0.x/24 subnet.

The easiest way to do this, would be to make all of your subnets "similar" to one diverse supernet (like most organizations do, to cross-site connect).

My recommendation to you:
If you are going to use the 10.8.x.x consortium, continue on with that by expanding your subnet range. Use 10.8.0.x for one network, 10.8.1.x for the next, etc. Then use subnet mask to expand out to how many networks you will have. Example: If you will have 10.8.0.x, 10.8.1.x, 10.8.2.x and 10.8.3.x, use a subnet mask of /22 OR 255.255.252.0. This will "join" all four networks into one super-net. However, your network may show some congestion, if you do it this way.

If you have some interest in setting it up more securely, piggy-backing is also an option, by setting up an actual firewall (or Server) to handle your DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) and DNS (Domain Name System), and filtering things into their own networks and providing ACLs (Access Control Lists) so that computers with "this ACL" can reach the NAS. This will be more complicated to setup, but once it's all setup, you can set static IPs for your devices in your network, so that you control which devices have access and which don't.

Lots of ways of going about it. The messiest being the supernet option. It's definitely the easiest, however.

Since they are two separate networks (just to ping back to the beginning here), set your OpenVPN servers inside those ranges, just don't set your DHCP to overlap, and set routes on your router (if it has the ability). Otherwise, my recommendation above is the most valid.

Comment: thank you very much for the advise.

i have tried to configure it like that.

Comment: helped me very much, but it was another issue
I did not configure the routing table at the route 192.168.2.1
I just added the route and it worked